# Why isn't "cómo se dice" "cómo dices"?

Tags: pronombres, conjugación, se

"Cómo se dice __", meaning "how do you say __", is confusing me.

Why is there `se`? Why is *dice* in *él/ella/usted* (3rd) form if "cómo se dice" means "how do **you** say __"? Why isn't it "cómo dices"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, it's possible to ask

> How do you say "father"?

or

> How does one say "father"?

These two questions are equivalent, because *you* has two meanings in English: first, a personal pronoun, as in "Do you want my phone number?" and second, "an unspecified person or people in general", as in "You get tired quicker when it's very hot out" (see http://www.thefreedictionary.com/you).

But in Spanish, *tú* **only** has the personal pronoun meaning.

Now, there is a third way you *could* do it in English, although it's a bit weird:

> How is "father" said?

That is the *passive voice*.  And the passive is what is commonly used in Spanish for vocabulary questions.  The passive is usually handled in Spanish by making the verb reflexive.  Here are some examples of a reflexive verb:

> El perro se rasca. (The dog scratches itself.)
>
> Yo me odio.  (I hate myself.)

And here are some reflexive verbs that function as passive expressions:

> Se contestan las preguntas en la clase.  (Questions are answered in class.)
>
> Las calificaciones se anuncian mañana.  (Grades are announced tomorrow.)

And that is the construction used in Spanish to talk about vocabulary, for example:

> En inglés, "padre" se traduce como "father."  (In English, "padre" is translated as "father.")
>
> En español, "papá" se dice más comúnmente que "padre."  (In Spanish, "papá" is said more commonly than "father.")

---

Side note: occasionally, you might hear "Cómo dices 'beans'?" because the exact vocabulary item for "beans" will depend on the country the speaker is from.  In one country, the commonly used word will be "frijoles" but in another country it might be something else, such as "habichuelas."  So in this case, one person might ask a friend from a different Spanish-speaking country, "How do you, personally, say 'beans'?" ("¿Cómo dices tú 'beans'?")

Answer (score 7):

To express **how do you say __??** in Spanish you can use either of your alternatives but in different contexts.

If you want to ask **in general** how something is pronounced the you will use the **se** sentence.

> ¿Cómo se dice *chicken* en español?
>     *Chicken* en español se dice pollo

If you want to ask a person how does he/she say something **specific** then you ask a personal question.

> ¿Cómo dices [tú] *car* en español?
>   Yo digo *carro*.
>   ¿y cómo dice *car* en español alguien de España?
>   Ellos dicen *coche*

There is no such a distinction in English because when you ask **how do you...** you could be asking to a specific [you] person or you could be making a general/impersonal question.

Answer (score 6):

In English, we make a distinction often between ***you*** you (the person we're taking to) and *you, generally* (a non-specific person, that is, *how does one say...?*). When we ask *how do you say...?* we more often than not are speaking generally.

Spanish has its own structures to speak generically, and that's what you see here, specifically this is the *se impersonal*. If we cared specifically about how the person we're speaking with would say a word (as opposed to other people, perhaps), then *¿Cómo. dices...?* would be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a literal translation between English and Spanish.

*Cómo se dice* - more or less translates to "how is it said".

You are asking a general term - how is it that everyone says chicken?

Whereas if you are asking a personal preference, you can say:

*¿Cómo dices?* if you are asking me how do I say something.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenido de nuevo. ¡Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!